# Element-wise multiplication of pandas by indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
                    "b" : [-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10,-11,-12],
                    "t" : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]})
df1.index = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [10,20,30],
                    "b" : [-10,-20,-30]})
df2.index = [2,3,4]
```

They look like this:

```
df1
    a   b   t
1   1  -1   1
1   2  -2   2
1   3  -3   3
2   4  -4   4
2   5  -5   5
2   6  -6   6
3   7  -7   7
3   8  -8   8
3   9  -9   9
4  10 -10  10
4  11 -11  11
5  12 -12  12

df2
    a   b
2  10 -10
3  20 -20
4  30 -30
```

So the columns of `df2` are a subset of the columns of `df1`. I want to multiply the rows of `df1` with the rows of `df2` where they have the same index and only retain the rows that consist of the intersection between their indices, i.e. basically

```
ls_keep = []
for i in range(len(df1)):
    for j in range(len(df2)):
        if df1.index[i] == df2.index[j]:
            df1.iloc[i]["a"] = df1.iloc[i]["a"] * df2.iloc[j]["a"]
            df1.iloc[i]["b"] = df1.iloc[i]["b"] * df2.iloc[j]["b"]
            ls_keep.append(i)

df1 = df1.iloc[ls_keep]
```

This gives me

```
     a    b   t
2   40   40   4
2   50   50   5
2   60   60   6
3  140  140   7
3  160  160   8
3  180  180   9
4  300  300  10
4  330  330  11
```

This code works as intended, but is very unprofessional and long in case there are more than just two columns. Is there a way to optimize it using functions of `pandas`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First filter only matched indices to new `DataFrame` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) and then multiple by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) with `df2.columns` for processing same columns in both `DataFrame`s:

```
df11 = df1[df1.index.isin(df2.index)].copy()
df11[df2.columns] = df11[df2.columns].mul(df2)
print (df11)
     a    b   t
2   40   40   4
2   50   50   5
2   60   60   6
3  140  140   7
3  160  160   8
3  180  180   9
4  300  300  10
4  330  330  11
```